# Django call function to save file cannot work

Tags: django, fileresponse

I am create Django project and create function for download file, But my project cannot work, File not response to save

`view.py`

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def index(request):
     BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
     filename = 'my_file.json'
     filepath = BASE_DIR + '/filedownload/' + filename
     download(request,filepath)
     return HttpResponse('Download File')

def download(request, path):
     file_path = path
     if os.path.exists(file_path):
     with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
          response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/x-download")
          response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
          return response
     raise Http404
```

> How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your download() returns response to your index()** and your index() returns its own response(not a response of download()). If you returns response of download() like below, it will works.

```py
import os
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def index(request):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    filename = 'my_file.json'
    filepath = BASE_DIR + '/filedownload/' + filename
    return download(request,filepath)

def download(request, path):
    file_path = path
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/x-download")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Comment: thank you very much i can do it